# Using Existing Blazor Server as Blazor WASM Backend

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am currently doing a project using Blazor and demonstrating some of the features that they have. I was thinking of creating a Blazor Server, WASM, and MBB version of this application.

My understanding is that Blazor WASM (PWA version) needs some sort of Server or API to access data or external API's.

I currently have a Blazor Sever application completed, and I was wondering if I could use that as a backbone or an intermediary between the Blazor WASM and data.

Any idea on how should I go about this?

Comment: Blazor server would be orthagonal to Blazor webassembly.  You should choose one or the other.  Depending on how you implemented the server version, it could be trivial to convert it to a webassembly version.  In practice, that is very unlikely, as when you start with the server version, you can do so many things that would be illegal in webassembly (such as accessing the server database directly) that it will probably end up being a big effort.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I was thinking of using the Blazor Server as the backbone of the WebAssembly app, this would make it so the webassembly is still acessing the data in a secure way, and I wouldn't have to develop another API project for it.

Comment: You can have both, of you do all data work on services your overhead will be smaller, and you won't do silly things like accessing a database from a component

Answer (score 1):

While you can reuse the data services, you will still need to expose actual HTTP endpoints for your WASM app - they need to be able to serialize the data you need to transfer between the server and the client. For example, WebAPI controllers that can rely on the database services you already have for your server-side blazor app.

Blazor WASM is like any other SPA framework you might have seen - it runs completely in the browser and needs some sort of API endpoint to fetch data.

The server-side blazor model is the odd one out by letting you interface directly with the data services on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I think I like your idea of going with adding a web api controller and using the services that I already have. As far as the components itself, I am guessing that I would have to modify my blazor components and paste it in the WASM project

Comment: Use the same components, just offload all data work into services described by interfaces. Then, the app implements new services depending on whether it is server or wasm.

Comment: Thanks for the commment! Will do try this out and see how it works :)